# Why does my calculator show $2^{-329} = 0?$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, numerical-methods, calculator

On my calculator, I usually get a $0$ when I divide something by $2$, a lot of times if that makes sense, but I was just wondering why does $2^{-329} = 0?$

Comment: It doesn't. Calculators [round](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding).

Comment: Consider that if $2^{-329}$ was zero, then $2^{-329} \times 2 = 2^{-328}$ would have to be zero too. And by the same logic $2^{-327}, 2^{-326}, \cdots 2^{0}$ would have to be as well. But $2^0 = 1$, contradiction.

Comment: About $9.14\times10^{-100}$, I think maybe it's because the exponent field display of a typical LCD calculator can only show down to $-99$?

Comment: I'm amazed that NOT ONE of the six answers so far has used the word "round".  Students often think calculators give EXACT answers whereas things done by hand are rounded.  That's the opposite of the truth.  All the confusion about arithmetic that's out there will persist until simple things are taught, one of which is that CALCULATORS ROUND.  +1 to "anon"'s comment.

Comment: @MichaelHardy wendy.krieger's answer is correct in that it says correctly that this is underflow; this is also rounding error (in that it rounds to the nearest representable number), but underflow is a much more specific description of what happened.

Comment: Michael Hardy -- My +1 goes to @AlvinWong whose comment explains why the typical calculator shows zero.

Comment: @AlvinWong One can test that by multiplying that "zero" by 2.

Comment: It's not even rounding.  Underflow happens even with $10^{-60}$ squared, where no rounding occurs. Also, one handles underfloe/overflow by different processes e.g. seperate the exponent to a different calculation.

Comment: @wendy.krieger Yes, but in some strict sense, rounding is the process by which the closest representable number is selected; so underflow is rounding to 0, but not in the usual way when mantissa needs to be truncated.

Comment: Underflow is underflow, and your program can decide what to do with it.  While it makes sense to set it to 0, this does not need to happen.  Underflow in computer addition (ie when -Z is less than the negatives can hold), sometimes is flooded modularly to the top of the table (-32769 = +32767).  The algorithms to handle overflow/underflow are different than those to handle rounding (which usually involves staving off calculations, and making the error count minimally).

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The precise name for the feature is [*underflow*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_underflow), which means it's less than the smallest number the registers can hold.  It's kind of like [*overflow*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_overflow).

Comment: I really love the fact that this uses the word, "feature"

Answer (score 35):

It doesn't. Your calculator can't handle a number of such a small magnitude. Specifically, $2^{-329}\approx 9.14\times 10^{-100}$, and I'm guessing that your calculator can only handle numbers of magnitude between $10^{-99}$ and $10^{99}$.

Comment: In contrast, IEEE double precision can represent the answer correctly (and exactly).

Comment: @Dan, that's true, the smallest number it can represent exactly is 2^−1074

Answer (score 30):

Your calculator gives you $0$ for $2^{-329}$ for the same reason that it gives you $0$ when you divide by $2$ a lot: Because $2^{-329}$ *is* dividing by $2$ a lot.  More precisely,

$$2^{-329}=\dfrac{1}{2^{329}}=\dfrac{1}{\text{huge number}}=\text{number so small your calculator doesn't know it from }0.$$

Note that $2^{-329}$ is what you get if you start with $1$ and divide by $2$ repeatedly, a total of $329$ times.

Answer (score 11):

The calculator doesn't have enough precision to store the number which is so small that the closest number it can represent is 0.

Similarly, the same thing happens when you try repeatedly square rooting a number on your calculator.

I.e. pick any positive number $n$ and evaluate $\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{...\sqrt{\sqrt{n}}}}}$. You'll find the calculator eventually returns $1.0$ when you do it enough times.

Answer (score 10):

You know from your algebra course (hopefully) that $2^x \neq 0$ for any $x$, so this has something to do with calculator doing something in appropriate. You were probably expecting something in scientific notation:
$$
2^{-329} = a \cdot 10^b
$$
for some $1 \leq a < 10$ and an integer $b$ (so that neither the right hand side nor the left hand side are zeroes, of course). Can you still compute this on your calculator? In your algebra class, you should have learned a trick to make insanely big (or insanely small, like this one) numbers manageable. Let's put this trick to action:
$$
b + \log_{10} a  = \log_{10} 2^{-329} = -329 \log_{10} 2 = -329 \cdot 0.30103 = -99.038869 
$$
If $1 \leq a < 10$, then $0 \leq \log_{10} a < 1$. So $b$ is the [integer floor part](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions) of the answer, and $\log_{10} a$ is the fractional part:
$$
 b = -100; \log_{10} a = 1 - 0.038869 = 0.961131; a = 10^{0.0.961131} = 9.14389
$$
Thus,
$$
2^{-329} = 9.14389 \cdot 10^{-100}
$$
as of course pointed out by everybody else in this thread.

Calculator is your (powerful) tool, but you still need to be smart in using that tool.

Comment: +1, even though probably useless to the person who asked.

Answer (score 2):

Because, the calculator has a limit, and the input of yours crosses that limit.
Your calculator calculates the value for the positive index first and then inverses it. Hence, it's underflowing its register values.